# Saving references to the func's in a slice

Tags: go

In this program I'm saving references to the functions that are returning specific implementations in a slice.

Within SpeakAll I'm calling each function to get it's corresponding object and calling Speak on it.

Issue: Unable to iterate through array and get an output

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XcAoG9j4_w)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IAnimal interface {
    Speak() string
}

type Cat struct {}
func (c Cat) Speak() string {
    return "meow!"
}

type Dog struct {}
func (d Dog) Speak() string {
    return "woof!"
}

type Zoo struct {
    Animals []func() IAnimal
}

func (zoo Zoo) AddAnimal(animal func() IAnimal) {
    if zoo.Animals == nil {
        zoo.Animals = make([]func() IAnimal, 0)
    }
    zoo.Animals = append(zoo.Animals, animal)
}

func (zoo Zoo) SpeakAll() {
    for _, animal := range zoo.Animals {
        fmt.Println(animal().Speak())
    }
}


func main() {
    catFunc := func() IAnimal {return Cat{}}
    dogFunc := func() IAnimal {return Dog{}}

    z := Zoo{}

    z.AddAnimal(catFunc)
    z.AddAnimal(dogFunc)

    z.SpeakAll()
}
```

Comment: you need AddAnimal to be a method on a pointer, e.g. `func (zoo *Zoo) AddAnimal(animal func() IAnimal) {` https://play.golang.org/p/Tlt4zzz4zH

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that AddAnimal has been defined as a method receiver on the Zoo type, not the *Zoo type.  This means that when you call z.AddAnimal(catFunc) you pass a copy of the Zoo (including the slice Animals) to the method, which then appends the function to this **copy** of the original Zoo, but not the original Zoo.

Change the method to a pointer receiver like this, and it will receive a pointer to the original struct:

```
func (zoo *Zoo) AddAnimal(animal func() IAnimal) {
```

Some additional things to consider:

1 - You don't need the following code - append will create the slice if it's nil:

```
if zoo.Animals == nil {
    zoo.Animals = make([]func() IAnimal, 0)
}
```

2 - In Go you generally don't prefix names with I for interface.

3 - If you really have a Zoo with a single slice in it, you could instead just add methods to a custom slice type:

```
type Zoo []func() IAnimal

func (zoo *Zoo) AddAnimal(animal func() IAnimal) {
    *zoo = append(*zoo, animal)
}

func (zoo Zoo) SpeakAll() {
    for _, animal := range zoo {
        fmt.Println(animal().Speak())
    }
}


func main() {
    catFunc := func() IAnimal {return Cat{}}
    dogFunc := func() IAnimal {return Dog{}}

    var z Zoo

    z.AddAnimal(catFunc)
    z.AddAnimal(dogFunc)

    z.SpeakAll()
}
```

Comment: Hi Colin, possible to remove animals from zoo once starting from zero indiex, `Array shift` method within SpeakAll method until slices are empty

Comment: Yes, again make the SpeakAll method a pointer receiver, then just truncate the slice after the range iteration.